# How to debug significant time difference between constructor and ngOnInit()

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I have an angular app, where i open an angular material dialog. The opening of the dialog is triggered from two different places in my code. When I trigger it from place A, the dialog component loads as fast as expected. When I trigger it from place B, the dialog components loads really slowly. I timed the difference between when the `constructor` is called and when `ngOnInit` is called:
Place A: 6 millisecons (i think this is normal)
Place B: ~2 seconds (way too long)

How can i debug this Problem? How can i see what angular, the rendering engine, etc.. is doing during these 2 seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please reproduce this scenario in https://stackblitz.com/ so I can check what will be real issue?

Comment: @Jitendra Its really hard to reproduce on stackblitz, because I can not isolate the issue. As I wrote above, it works when called from one place and doesn't work when called from another. So something happening in my code before or some state in my application seem to influence the behaviour of the dialog. Thats why I asked for more general tips how i can debug this issue.